# Django Redirect view with args

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have a problem with redirection in Django :

**my view**

```
def myP(request,namep):    
     return render(request,"site/myP.html")

def create(request):    
    nom="alaild"    
    ....    
    return redirect(reverse(myP,namep=nom))
```

**urls to this views**

```
url(r'^create$', 'create', name='create'),    
url(r'^myp/(?P<namep>\d+)','myP', name="myp"),
```

I have this error :

```
reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

I want create view redirects to myP view but myP view have 1 argument and I don't know how make...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, `nom` is a string, but in your url pattern you are using `\d+` (one or more digits).

A common approach is to accept a 'slug' which can contain letters, digits, underscores and hyphens:

```
url(r'^myp/(?P<namep>[\w-]+)','myP', name="myp"),
```

Then you need to fix the syntax of your [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) call. Either of the following should work.

```
reverse(myP, kwargs={'namep': nom})
reverse(myP, args=(nom,))
```

Answer (score 2):

May be

`reverse(myP, kwargs={'namep': nom})`

Comment: No I have this error : NoReverseMatch at /creation-projet

Reverse for 'site.views.myp' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'namept': u'avecdcdzdzacd'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myp/(?P<namep>\\d+)']

Comment: In exeception I see 'namept' arg but in urls pattern you use 'namep'